# Во время входа в modx, страница просто обновляется

Tags: modx

Вписываю /manager и страница просто обновляется, хотя раньше перенаправляла в modx. Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: А что изменилось между "раньше" и "теперь"? Может быть появился какой-то редирект, или имеют место ошибки? Может быть что-то в системном логе /core/cache/logs или в консоли браузера при входе в /manager?

Comment: Во всех браузерах не работал. Ничего не делал, просто резко перестало работать. Из вариантов, кэш чистил

Comment: если в логах ничего нет, как вариант -  обновите MODX до текущей или последней версии